# PHP wrong folder ? include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear'

Tags: php, path, webserver

I need to install this feature on my webserver. this error message is looking for `/usr/share/php` COLON `/usr/share/pear`

my php installation rests in `/usr/share/php5` , and I do not have a `/usr/share/pear` folder

What does colon mean in that syntax, "and" ?

if the path is wrong I'm not sure how to change that in this script, I dont want to change the `share/php5` to `php`, or is that recommended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does colon mean in that syntax, "and" ?

Yes, something like that. Its the path separator and you can compare it with a comma ",".

> if the path is wrong I'm not sure how to change that in this script, I dont want to change the share/php5 to php, or is that recommended?

You can change the value in the `php.ini`. You can find out, which configuration files are used with `php --ini`. Or you change it withing your script with

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/usr/share/php5');
```

If this is a system-wide behaviour (means: PHP is not working probably at all), you should change it in the configuration. Its just for this one application, then you can use `set_include_path()`.

Comment: do you know if having "php5" folders is common? php in the past for me has usually just worked at this level, or was taken care of by the host

Comment: I also have an folder `/usr/share/php5`, but its almost empty. In `/usr/share/php` is my PEAR-installation (Ubuntu). However, it often depends on your system  configuration and changes you made, whats your locations. In some cases the paths defined in `php.ini` does not match your filesystem, but its no big deal to fix it.

Comment: my php5 folder only has a php.ini-dist which I understand contains the defaults of php if there is no php.ini present